# GPS navigation - Real time navigation using google maps in Ionic 1

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, gps

I have been working in this project for a month and  i have made it almost complete except the last functionality, which is real time navigation from current location to destination in `ionic framework`. I have google a lot, saw links of stack overflow but all I get is there is no way to get real time location legally provided by google in their `API`. So In Ionic framework, Currently I am getting current `lat` and `long` and destination `lat` and `long` using service `API`.

Is this possible we use the same direction service `response`, and plot some `pinpoints` in the route between the current location and destination, and after some fixed interval check user location.

Will it behave at least near to that functionality which i am trying to make ? Or will it be legal to use the response from the service `API` as a base point to achieve this feature?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem now. Did you find any way of doing it?